# E flat to B flat on Flute?

Tags: fingering, flute

I’m playing the piece Menuet from L’Arlésienne Suite No.2 and there are multiple instances where E flat to B flat sixteenth notes are played. Obviously it is a possible transition to do, but I feel like the slur sounds rough when compared to the smoothness of the song. Are there any alternate fingerings on this part that I can use to improve the overall quality of the song?

Edit: For clarification this E flat 6 to B flat 5, the sixteenth notes are going from the E flat down to the B flat, not up.

Comment: Which fingering are you currently using?

Comment: I’m using the regular E flat fingering with all fingers down, and then the B flat fingering with first finger down on the left hand, regular thumb key, first finger down on right hand and then the right hand pinky key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a lot of choice for those two notes. You could use the thumb Bb instead which would allow your right hand to move more as one unit. You could also leave the Ab key pressed down and sacrifice some intonation (which on a trill isn't that important) allowing you to concentrate more on your other fingers. A combination of these two might help you smooth it out more. I'm kind of wondering why you aren't already using the thumb Bb in a piece like this.

For a more radical approach you could shift your left hand index finger over to hold down both C and the Bb key, but I'm not sure how much this would help.

Comment: Thank you! My flute is currently getting repaired, and I just received the piece when I first posted this. I was going to play around with the alternate fingerings once I got my flute back, but I figured it would be best to ask on here.